# Sort Select Option In Optgroup JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, optgroup

I have a select like below, and i want to sort this select in alphabetical order. (with Jquery)

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Potatoes" >
    <option value="1" > Value 1 </option>
    <option value="3" > Value 3 </option>
    <option value="2" > Value 2 </option>
   </optgroup>

   <optgroup label="Banana" >
    <option value="1" > C </option>
    <option value="3" > A </option>
    <option value="2" > S </option>
   </optgroup>
 </select>
```

I only want to sort the options inside the optgroup. I don't want to sort the optgroup.

In order to have :

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Potatoes" >
    <option value="1" > Value 1 </option>
    <option value="2" > Value 2 </option>
    <option value="3" > Value 3 </option>
   </optgroup>

   <optgroup label="Banana" >
      <option value="3" > A </option>
      <option value="1" > C </option>
      <option value="2" > S </option>
   </optgroup>
 </select>
```

I only found a way to sort the select with the optgroups...

Comment: Can you not sort them in the source, rather than band-aid'ing the order with javascript later?

Comment: Nop, because i have many languages in my website... And this is not the same order in all languages.

Comment: Fair enough, though that makes me wonder then how you are going to write a sorting algorithm that works for all languages.

Comment: Well I use a translator editor, so the language doesn't really mind.

Comment: The alphabetical order stays the same.

Comment: So, you're saying the order *will* be the same.  So I repeat my first question.  Why can't you fix the order in the source?

Comment: No, this wasn't what I mean.


Whatever the language, the sort remains the same.

Comment: I found the solution in jquery
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/dt3b6fmc/

```
$(function() {
  $('optgroup').each(function() {
    var optgroup = this;
    $( 'option', this ).sort(function(a,b) {
     return $(a).text() > $(b).text();
        }).appendTo(optgroup);
  });
});
```

Does that satisfy your needs?

Comment: Yes, I did something like this too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [localCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to compare html string of your options

Also used function to get selector result as array using [toArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort)

and the use of [.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort)
See bellow snippet

```js
$('select optgroup').each(function(index,elmt){
  result = $(elmt).find("option").toArray().sort((option1, option2) => option1.innerHTML.localeCompare(option2.innerHTML));
  
  $(result).appendTo(elmt);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <optgroup label="Potatoes" >
    <option value="1" > Value 1 </option>
    <option value="3" > Value 3 </option>
    <option value="2" > Value 2 </option>
   </optgroup>

   <optgroup label="Banana" >
    <option value="1" > C </option>
    <option value="3" > A </option>
    <option value="2" > S </option>
   </optgroup>
 </select>
```